# how to extract the data from from website and save the into txt file

Tags: python

i am using python 3.3.3 and trying to extract the data as well as links in txt file. I have tried this code but it is not creating neither saving any thing in the file.At console if i would write "print(s)" then still does not shows anythings to me.

```
import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org") as url:
    s = url.read()
    url.close()
#I'm guessing this would output the html source code?
#print(s)

# write data
ff = open("ne.txt", "w")
ff.write('s')
ff.close()
```

if i am doing wrong then please tell me the correct criteria because i am also understanding and studying from internet resources.

Any help please....

Comment: What you did wrong there is that you wrote the string `'s'` and not the content of the variable `s`. The line had to be: `ff.write(s)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path_to_file)`

All code:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.python.org", "/home/user/ne.txt")
```

Comment: I would just use wget, if it is an option

Comment: urllib.request.urlretrieve(http://www.python.org, C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s) like this where "s" is the folder????

Comment: did nt understand properly are u asking to replace urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path_to_file) with urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.python.org") as url or in filing portion?

Comment: `urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.python.org", "/home/user/file.txt")` for example

Comment: if u have a look i am also creating file so shell i remove this?

Comment: replace `urlopen` by `urlretrieve`, this function save file to disk, you don't need to create file by `open` function after `urlretrieve`

Comment: i have written this : import urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://www.python.org" , "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\python\s\newfile.txt") as url:
    s = url.read()
    url.close() and giving me syntax error "unicodeescape cant decode byte" idk wts this??

Comment: And you write string `'s'` to file, not a variable `s`, so you just can replace `ff.write('s')` to `ff.write(s)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64013/discussion-between-serkos-and-user3440716).